# Mimicking the basic interface of std::stack

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, reinventing-the-wheel, stack

I am trying to mimic `std::stack` in my implementation (just the basic interface - no iterators / allocators).  Since I was having trouble handling all the memory allocation/deallocation, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Although my implementation seems to work flawlessly, I'm still not confident about these things:

1. There is no memory-leak
2. All the routines are fully performance and space-optimized
3. My usage of Copy-and-Swap idiom is correct
4. There isn't any better way of displaying the contents of a stack (see the overloaded `operator<<`).

Could you please review it to see if it could be improved?

```
using  namespace std;
template<typename T> struct mystack_node  // The data structure for representing the "nodes" of the stack
{
    T data;
    mystack_node *next;
};

template<typename T> class mystack;
template<typename T>ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,const mystack<T> &a);

template<typename T> class  mystack
{
    unsigned int stack_size;  // A variable keeping the record of number of nodes present in the stack
    mystack_node<T> *stack_top;  //  A pointer pointing to the top of the stack
    void mystack_swap(mystack &a,mystack &b)  //  Swap function used in the assignment  operator ( Copy-and-Swap Idiom )
    {
        swap(a.stack_size,b.stack_size);
        swap(a.stack_top,b.stack_top);
    }
public:
    mystack():stack_size(0),stack_top(NULL) {}  //  Default Constructor
    mystack(const mystack& other):stack_size(0),stack_top(NULL)  //  Copy constructor
    {
        int i=0;
        vector<T> vec(other.stack_size);  //  A vector for storing a backup of all the nodes in the "other" stack
        mystack_node<T> *temp=other.stack_top;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            vec[i++]=temp->data;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        for(i=(int)vec.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            push(vec[i]);
        }
    }
    ~mystack()  //  Destructor
    {
        mystack_node<T> *temp=stack_top;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            delete stack_top;
            stack_top=temp;
        }
    }
    mystack& operator = (mystack other)  // Assignment operator
    {
        mystack_swap(*this,other);
        return *this;
    }
    void push(const T &val)  // Add a new node to the stack
    {
        mystack_node<T> *temp=new mystack_node<T>;
        temp->data=val;
        temp->next=stack_top;
        stack_top=temp;
        stack_size++;
    }
    void pop()    //  Remove the "top" node from the stack
    {
        if(stack_top!=NULL)   //  Don't do anything if the stack is already empty
        {
            mystack_node<T> *temp=stack_top->next;
            delete stack_top;
            stack_top=temp;
            stack_size--;
        }
    }
    unsigned int size() // Returns the number of nodes in the stack
    {
        return stack_size;
    }
    bool empty() // Returns whether if the stack is empty or not
    {
        return stack_size==0;
    }
    T top()  // Returns the "top" node from the stack
    {
        return (*stack_top).data;  // Deliberately left Out-of-Bound exception checking...
    }
    friend ostream& operator << <T> (ostream&,const mystack&);
};
template<typename T>ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,const mystack<T> &a) // Output operator to show the contents of the stack
{
    mystack_node<T> *temp=a.stack_top;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        out<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return out;
}
```

**EDIT:**

1. Made `size()`, `empty()` and `top()` as `const` functions.
2. Changed the type of `stack_size` from `unsigned int` to `size_t`.
3. Defined `struct mystack_node`in the private section of `class mystack` so that it is inaccessible to any other part of the code.

```
using  namespace std;

template<typename T> class mystack;
template<typename T>ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,const mystack<T> &a);

template<typename T> class  mystack
{
    struct mystack_node  // The data structure for representing the "nodes" of the stack
    {
        T data;
        mystack_node *next;
    };
    size_t stack_size;  // A variable keeping the record of number of nodes present in the stack
    mystack_node *stack_top;  //  A pointer pointing to the top of the stack
    void mystack_swap(mystack &a,mystack &b)  //  Swap function used in the assignment  operator ( Copy-and-Swap Idiom )
    {
        swap(a.stack_size,b.stack_size);
        swap(a.stack_top,b.stack_top);
    }
public:
    mystack():stack_size(0),stack_top(NULL) {}  //  Default Constructor
    mystack(const mystack& other):stack_size(0),stack_top(NULL)  //  Copy constructor
    {
        int i=0;
        vector<T> vec(other.stack_size);  //  A vector for storing a backup of all the nodes in the "other" stack
        mystack_node *temp=other.stack_top;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            vec[i++]=temp->data;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        for(i=(int)vec.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            push(vec[i]);
        }
    }
    ~mystack()  //  Destructor
    {
        mystack_node *temp=stack_top;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            delete stack_top;
            stack_top=temp;
        }
    }
    mystack& operator = (mystack other)  // Assignment operator
    {
        mystack_swap(*this,other);
        return *this;
    }
    void push(const T &val)  // Add a new node to the stack
    {
        mystack_node *temp=new mystack_node;
        temp->data=val;
        temp->next=stack_top;
        stack_top=temp;
        stack_size++;
    }
    void pop()    //  Remove the "top" node from the stack
    {
        if(stack_top!=NULL)   //  Don't do anything if the stack is already empty
        {
            mystack_node *temp=stack_top->next;
            delete stack_top;
            stack_top=temp;
            stack_size--;
        }
    }
    size_t size() const // Returns the number of nodes in the stack
    {
        return stack_size;
    }
    bool empty() const // Returns whether if the stack is empty or not
    {
        return stack_size==0;
    }
    T top() const  // Returns the "top" node from the stack
    {
        return (*stack_top).data;  // Deliberately left Out-of-Bound exception checking...
    }
    friend ostream& operator << <T> (ostream&,const mystack&);
};
template<typename T>ostream& operator <<(ostream& out,const mystack<T> &a) // Output operator to show the contents of the stack
{
    typename mystack<T>::mystack_node *temp=a.stack_top;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        out<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on `Edit 2`:

[Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice):

```
using  namespace std;
```

The `mystack_node` may be a structure. But it can still have members and construcors. If you add a constructor you will make your life simpler in the add or push below.

```
    struct mystack_node  // The data structure for representing the "nodes" of the stack
    {
        T data;
        mystack_node *next;

        // Add
        mystack_node(T const& d, mystack_node* n)
             : data(d)
             , next(n)
        {}
    };
```

As noted elsewhere. Defined a standard swap function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

```
    void mystack_swap(mystack &a,mystack &b)
```

The copy constructor is broken.
You copy the data into a local vector then don't do anything with it.

```
    mystack(const mystack& other):stack_size(0),stack_top(NULL)
```

You are on the correct line when you try an make it exception safe with a vector. But you don't need to go so far. You just need to make sure if there is an exception during the copy that you free any allocated memory. Note if an exception is thrown from the constructor then the destructor will not be called.

As you only have a singly linked list I would use recursion to track the copy.

```
    mystack(const mystack& other)
        : stack_size(0)
        , stack_top(NULL)
    {
        try
        {
             recursive_copy(other.stack_top);
             stack_size = other.stack_size;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
             // If there is an exception
             // Release all resources then
             // let the exception continue to propagate.
             release_stack();
             throw;
        }            
    }

    void recursive_copy(mystack_node* head)
    {
         if (head == NULL)
         {    return;
         }
         // Recursively go to the end of the list
         recursive_copy(head->next);

         // On your way back up.
         // Build each node onto the stack.
         stack_top = new mystack_node(head.data, stack_top);
    }
```

In the destructor I would have used a `for(;;)` loop. That way you can put all the control in one place. Since the constructor now can potentially relase also use the same function as the constructor.

```
    ~mystack()  //  Destructor
    {
        release_stack();
    }

    release_stack() noexcept  /* or C++03 throws() */
    {
        mystack_node* next;
        for(mystack_node* loop=stack_top; loop; loop = next)
        {
            next =loop->next;
            delete loop;
        }
    }
```

By adding the constructor to `mystack_node` the push becomes much more readable.

```
    void push(const T &val)  // Add a new node to the stack
    {
        stack_top = new mystack_node(val, stack_top);
        stack_size++;
    }
```

Since you do not have control of the type T. You must assume that all calls to its methods are not exception safe. This includes the destructor. This means you need to write your code so that your object is fully mutated before calling an exception unsafe method.

```
    void pop()    //  Remove the "top" node from the stack
    {
        if(stack_top!=NULL)   //  Don't do anything if the stack is already empty
        {
            mystack_node* oldTop = stack_top;
            stack_top=stack_top->next;
            stack_size--;

            // Put the delete at the end.
            // Your object has now been fully mutated
            // Thus if the destructor throws it will not harm your object
            // by leaving it in an undefined state.
            delete oldTop;

            // In your old version where you called delete before modifying
            // stack_top. An exception would have left your object pointing
            // at an object that had been deleted.
        }
    }
```

Why not return a reference to the top node?

```
    T top() const  // Returns the "top" node from the stack
```

If you do this you probably need two versions. A const and a non cost version.

```
    T& top();  // See below.
    T const& top() const   {return const_cast<mystack>(*this).top();}
```

Rather than dereference the object then use the `.` operator. It may be best to just use the `->` operator for readability.

```
        return (*stack_top).data;

        // Easier to read as:
        return stack_top->data;
```

One minor thing.

```
     mystack_node   *oldTop;    // Looks very C like

     // In C++ it is more common to put the * on the left with the type.
     // The argument being the `*` is part of the type, and C++ is
     // all about type correctness.
     //
     // Its not a big thing and there is a lot of code your way around
     // but it is in the minority (and it helps C++ developers spot
     // C developers pretending to code in C++  :-) )

     mystack_node*   oldTop;    // More C++ like
```

Comment: Great answer!! I tried to compile my code after making the mentioned changes, but got a compiler warning regarding your `release_stack() throw()` function  -  `warning: for increment expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]`   [my attempt](http://ideone.com/XUI6Yd)

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi: Fixed a bug. Change `loop != next` to `loop = next`

Comment: Also, in the `pop()` function, you have mentioned `// Thus if the destructor throws it will not harm your object `. I do not understand under what circumstances would a destructor throw an exception?? ( I don't have a good understanding of exception-handling )

Comment: You are not supposed to throw from a destructor but you can. You do not know how `T` is implemented or even who is implementing `T`. So you must assume that they are idiots. If the destructor of T throws an exception (when you call `delete oldTop;`) then it should not affect your class.

Answer (score 7):

The recommended swap function implementation is as a `friend` named `swap` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

```
public:
...
friend void swap(mystack &a, mystack &b)
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(a.stack_size, b.stack_size);
    swap(a.stack_top, b.stack_top);
}
```

And the assignment operator is:

```
mystack& operator= (mystack other)
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that `::swap(mystack&, mystack&)` is still an external function and *not* a member function, **even though it is defined within the class definition**.

Comment: @William Thanks for reviewing my code. But could you please explain what difference does it make whether i make `swap()` a friend or a private function??

Comment: @Lstor I am unable to fathom why `swap` isn't a member function. Would you care to explain in a little more depth??

Comment: Section 11.3.6 of the C++11 standard states: *A function can be defined in a* `friend` *declaration of a class [iff] the class is a non-local class, the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope.* The easiest way to tell is because it has `friend` in front. [See this demonstration](http://codepad.org/BBNKtaE9) (remove line #14 to get it to compile).

Comment: @Lstor I know that a friend function is not a member function! But I haven't declared swap as a friend function!! ( It is declared as `swap(mystack&, mystack&)` and not as `friend swap(mystack&, mystack&)` ).  The only function which is declared as friend in my code is the `operator <<`.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi I am talking about the `swap` in @WilliamMorris' answer (which is why it was posted as a comment to his answer).

Comment: @Lstor oops! :P  Thanks for the help anyways!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695548/public-friend-swap-member-function

Answer (score 5):

1. You may run a high risk of memory leaks when using raw structures, especially with pointers.  Memory-management is not one of my strong points, so I won't say too much about that.  For learning purposes, you should be okay as long you maintain good habits (accompany each `new` with `delete`, etc).
2. Memory-management still plays a big role here, considering your stack is dynamic (as it lacks a `full()` and uses nodes).  Again, watch your memory and pointer usage.
3. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), I think you're using it correctly.
4. With a linked list type structure, that may be as good as you can get it.  For a dynamically-allocated array, on the other hand, you would just loop through it.  Overall, you won't attain superb data output unless you use iterators.  This is okay for a basic implementation, though.

---

- [Do not use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- The `class` declarations and implementations should be noticeably separate, even if they're in one file.  I had to scrounge for that `};` to see where your declarations ended.  Generally, you may still keep your accessors and mutators within the declarations as they'll automatically become `inline`.
- The node `struct` should be kept `private` within your class since it's a data member and shouldn't be exposed.
- If you're using C++11, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.
- You're not technically putting anything into your output stream.  Yours is called `out`, but you're still using `std::cout`.
- Your accessors (`size()`, `empty()`, and `top()`) should be declared with `const` since they just `return` data members:

  ```
  unsigned int size() const
  ```
- `size()` should return a `std::size_t`.  This is located in `<cstddef>`.
- If you're keeping careful track of `stack_size`, `pop()` could just check if the stack size is zero (using `empty()`).

**Follow-up on comments:**

1. `full()` was just my name for a common `bool` function for determining if a static structure has reached its maximum size.  With a dynamic structure like yours, this is not needed.
2. Consider this piece of code:

   ```
   for (auto iter = container.cbegin(); iter != container.cend(); ++iter)
   {
       std::cout << *iter;
   }
   ```

   This is one of a few C++11 ways of iterating through an STL storage container (such as `std::vector`).  Here, let `structure` be a name of such container and `iter` an iterator of this container (defined within the implementation).  These containers are designed in such a way that, if utilized correctly, you will avoid runtime errors with them.  In this case, using iterators *instead of indices* ensures that you'll not go out-of-bounds when accessing the container.
3. You simply need to move it to the `private` section of the class.  In order for `operator<<` to recognize your data members, declare it a `friend` and put it inside the class.  This particular operator doesn't belong to any one `class`, so you also cannot declare it as part of your own `class` with the `::` operator (in case you were curious).  There's plenty of info on all these `operator`s, so read up!
4. In and of itself, I don't think so.  The reason I've mentioned dynamically-allocated arrays is because stack elements aren't accessed the same way as linked lists.  The former deals with popping data from the top, whereas the former can have any node removed anywhere within the structure.  However, you're not wrong about using a linked list; it's still another way to implement a stack.
5. Not a huge difference, but I think it's a bit more readable with `empty()`.  With linked lists, `NULL` is necessary for determining if the list head is pointing to a node (not empty) or the `NULL` address (empty).  Overall, I'd say it's up to you.  Again, you should make sure that your element count is maintained, otherwise you'll have problems.

Comment: `op=` taking a parameter by value and then swapping it is the copy-and-swap idiom he is talking about. It should be like he wrote.

Comment: @Lstor: Oh, right.  Forgot about that.  I'm still working on my answer.

Comment: @Jamal Thanks for taking the time to review my code!!.. Your answer was very helpful.However,I am not able to understand few things in it -: 1). What is this `full` you are talking about??  2). How can iterators be used to improve the output process??  3). Could you please show me a demo on how to make `mystack_node` as a private struct of `mystack`?? [ I tried to shift the structure inside the class (as a normal struct and not as a template ), but then the output operator wasn't able to see `mystack_node *temp`!! ( and i don't know how to fix it )]

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi: I'll follow-up on this right now.

Comment: Some other things too! -:   4). Will there be any performance gain if i use a dynamic array instead of a "linked list type structure"?? ( besides the 3x performance gain in the copy constructor)    5). What difference does it make if I use `empty()` instead of comparison with `NULL`

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi `std::stack` is by default implemented on top of a `std::deque`, which uses an array. (C++11 standard section 23.3.3.1.1:  *A deque is a sequence container that, like a* `vector` *, supports random access iterators.*) Using an array gives locality of reference, random access (accessing index *n* is `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`), and so on.